# Wordpress custom function get_post_like_slug not working?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a custom **WP 3.5** function and I have no idea why it doesn't work... I'm sure that the error is inside the SQL query. What the function tries to do is to get a post from specific category where the post's slug begins with $post_name.

```
function get_post_like_slug($post_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    $page_name = substr($post_name, 0, -1).'%';
    $id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) WHERE ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 5 AND $wpdb.post_name LIKE %s)", $post_name ));

    if ( $id )
        return ($id);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you move your solution to an answer and explain what you did?  It will be more helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this on another post about properly using the like statement with wordpress.

Might be something like this:

```
$id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID FROM
  $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID =
  $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) WHERE
  ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 5 AND $wpdb.post_name
  LIKE %s)", '%' . like_escape($post_name) . '%' ));
```

And here is a link to the post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8847

Comment: hmm, you helped me realise that there using LIKE in wpdb can be a mess, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! What I did was to prepend "$wpdb->" on each table name and escape % character (%%). The function below works now:

```
function get_post_like_slug($post_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_name = substr($post_name, 0, -1);
    $id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id WHERE post_name LIKE %s AND $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id=5 LIMIT 1", $post_name.'%%' ));

    if ( $id )
        return ($id);
    return null;
}
```